# UWP WebView with "glass" layer not receiving pointer/touch events

Tags: webview, uwp, hittest, routed-events

I would like to apply a semi-transparent "glass" layer over a portion of a WebView, similar to this:

[image: screenshot]

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Sample.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <WebView
            Source="http://news.google.com"
        />

        <Rectangle
            Fill="Red"
            Opacity="0.25"
            IsHitTestVisible="False"
            MaxWidth="200"
        />

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

The code-behind:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace Sample
{
    public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
    {
        public BlankPage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that while mouse is over the reddish rectangle, the mouse pointer is an arrow (when hovering over hyperlinks), and tapping/clicking has no effect on the WebView. It looks like "IsHitTestVisible=False" doesn't actually work, and the WebView is not receiving events.

I found a document explaining hit-testing (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh758286#hit_testing) that says "WebView controls have special hit testing behavior" - but still, it seems that my sample should work.

The questions are:

1. Is the current behavior a bug?
2. Is there a workaround?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the current behavior a bug?

No,it isn't a bug. This is because the last element declared in XAML is the element that draws on top. In your code snippet,[`Rectangle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.rectangle.aspx) is rendered on top of the [`WebView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) control. It cannot get the focus of `WebView` control when point to `Rectangle`. It has no relationship with [IsHitTestVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.ishittestvisible) property.

> Is there a workaround?

I changed the rendered order for `WebView` and `Rectangle`, and set `Opacity` property for 'WebView' instead of `Rectangle`, which may have similar effects.

```
  <Rectangle
      MaxWidth="200"
      Fill="Red"   />
  <WebView Source="http://news.google.com"    Opacity="0.75"/>
```

And the result:

[image]